# Form process handling

Tags: php, forms

I am not well versed in this area and the other topics did not really help me. I tried using different portions to edit a PHP handler for a form and it did not work.

I get the email after the user clicks submit, however it is blank.
Also, this code i have has no validations for users trying to inject items.

Can someone help me add some validations and have the information appear in the email?

Any help is appreciated

EDIT NUMBER 2 SOLVED!:::::
Got the PHP and the JS talking nicely now. all is working. Had the wrong PHP file name in the JS code.

```html
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'MYADDRESS';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
 $to = $myemail; 
 $email_subject = "Contact Form Submission: $name";
 $email_body = "You have received a new submission from your website. ".
 " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Phone: $phone \n Message: \n $message"; 
 
 $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
 
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 //redirect to the 'thank you' page
 // header('Location: index.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
 <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

```js
// JavaScript contact form Document
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('form#contact-form').submit(function() {
 $('form#contact-form .error').remove();
 var hasError = false;
 $('.requiredField').each(function() {
 if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You forgot to enter your '+labelText+'</span>');
    $(this).addClass('inputError');
    hasError = true;
    } else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if(!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You entered an invalid '+labelText+'</span>');
    $(this).addClass('inputError');
    hasError = true;
    }
    }
    });
    if(!hasError) {
    $('form#contact-form input.submit').fadeOut('normal', function() {
    $(this).parent().append('');
    });

     $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "contact-form-handler.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
     $('form#contact-form').slideUp("fast", function() { $(this).before('<div class="col-lg-7 mx-auto success-box success"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/support.png" alt=""><p>Thank you. Your Email was sent successfully. <br> <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i></p>  </div>');
     $("#loader").hide();
     })
            }           
       });
    
    return false;
    }
 
   });
});
```

Comment: This reads as "please do this for me". Include what you've tried in this post, and we can help where you've gone wrong.

Comment: I was trying to validate items and used different parts from different posts and nothing worked. In just looking at questions this code looks too simple. The only thing that makes it to my inbox is the subject line.

Comment: Again, "nothing worked". Post what you've tried.

Comment: edited post above

Comment: OK, so that looks like the validation is fine. What errors are you getting?

Comment: When I use the larger code...I never get the email. When I use the small code it just shows the subject line "New Form Submission From Website". I am trying right now to see what other files from the "better" code with validations etc is using. THis is what I get when I buy a template =\

Comment: So debug why the mailer isn't working. `$m->Send();` might return a value indicating if it was true or false. Add some echo statements and figure out why it's not sending. `var_dump()`, `print_r()`, and `echo ...; exit()` are your friends.

Comment: FRANKERZ thanks. had wrong filename in the URL path in the JS. All is working now. If you can look at the code above. There is a generic form validator script that runs also. I did not post that, got if from JS coder website.